# How do i keep a div at 16x9 based on height of the window? i am using jw player

Tags: resolution, jwplayer, aspect

i am using jw player and it does not play well with widescreen monitors when put into a div that is 100% height and 100% width. When the page is wider than 16x9, the player just overflows vertically and controls can't be seen.

how can i make the containing div keep it's 16x9 width based on the height of the window?